# Aurelia - How to do composite applications that can be loaded at runtime

Tags: plugins, bundler, aurelia, composite

What I'm trying to do in Aurelia, is something like Prism is doing in WPF- Composite applications.

So lets say I have a "shell" application that defines the main application layout, then i have modules that I can plugin at run-time. Those modules can be an Aurelia application per se or Aurelia plugin (don't know what to use - need recommendation).
When loaded, the module needs to add it's menu items to the main application menu to expose it's features.

> This is a mockup of the application:

[image: The Main application shell that shows modules/features in the menu on the left side.]

Each module can have multiple menu items and can be pretty complex.

I'm using latest Typescript, Aurelia-CLI to create the application, and I'm using the built-in bundler : [Aurelia's new built-in bundler](https://aurelia.io/docs/cli/cli-bundler/#introduction).

So What I don't know is:

1. Those modules/features - what must they be? (Maybe Aurelia Plugins, or another Aurelia application?)
2. How to load those modules/features at run-time? (like deploy it in some plugins folder and tell the main shell application to load them)
3. How to modify the main menu and add new menu items from the loaded module?

Please help

Comment: would love to see a core-member answer that, as it can be very helpful in a lot of scenarios. don't know why it got down-voted.

Answer (score 0):

Aurelia supports ultra dynamic applications. Also, there have been other community members who have had similar requirements and was able to resolve it. So I think the scenario is possible.

---

1. It seems the sub-application can just be a route.How/where to load the route should be determined based on the application URL
2. Those modules doesn't need to do anything specific, they can just be a normal, plain JS/TS class with lifecycle methods to handle activation/deactivation. I guess that main shell and all sub-applications need to share a common URL, you cannot have more than one router.
3. There could be a singleton/central store for new route to register information about loaded features, or it can be loaded upfront by a configuration file/metadata file or a database fetch.

Here is a similar question from another community member that I think can help you see how to glue things to https://discourse.aurelia.io/t/dynamicaly-load-routes/1906

Comment: Thanks, I will look